# INTNX equivalent in R

Tags: r, date

I am currently working on replicating a SAS code to R.
In SAS, there is INTNX function that helps to advance a date by a given interval. 
For example -

```
intnx('month','2013/12/10',3) = 2014/03/10
```

I was wondering if there is a function in R that works in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lubridate` package you can simply do this:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd("2013/12/10") + months(3)
[1] "2014-03-10 UTC"
```

Note  also if you want to add a month without exceeding the last day of the new month, you should use `%m+`:

```
ymd("2013/01/31") %m+% months(1)
[1] "2013-02-28 UTC"
```

Comment: I think the above is fine, but you have to careful: `as.Date("1985-10-31") + months(4)` will give you a "NA" with lubridate 1.3.3.  I'm not sure what the function is doing internally, but it seems as if it was trying to create February 31st, which makes no sense.  Maybe someone has a solution?

Answer (score 2):

There is. You could do:

seq(as.Date("2013-12-10"), length=2, by="3 months")[2]

[1] "2014-03-10"

Comment: But does this work for a column as well? For example, I want to use this function on a date column where I replace "2013-12-10" by ds$date, then I get an error.